# Retrieve most recent records with conditions

Tags: postgresql

Here is my `foo` data model (there will be multiple entries for each id):

```
foo_id: int
status: enum(success, fail, noop)
created: datetime
```

I want to create a query that will ultimately remove records from this table and put them in a `historical_foo` table with the same table design.

The criteria for the query is that entries older than 30 days should be removed EXCEPT for records that contain the most recent success or most recent non-success for a specific `foo_id`,

My first pass is (pseudo query)

```
with old_entries as (
    select * from foo where (foo.date - today) > 30
),
recent_successes as (
    select id, MAX(created) from old_entries where old_entries.status = 'success' group by id
),
recent_non_successes as (
    select id, MAX(created) from old_entries where old_entries.status != 'success' group by id
),
select * from foo where id not in (recent_successes or recent_non_successes)
```

Foo table:

```
| pk  | foo_id | status  | created    |
|   1 |      1 | success | 2018-03-01 |
|   2 |      1 | failure | 2018-02-01 |
|   3 |      1 | noop    | 2018-01-01 |
|   4 |      2 | success | 2018-01-01 |
|   5 |      2 | failure | 2018-01-01 |
|   6 |      3 | failure | 2018-02-01 |
|   7 |      3 | failure | 2018-01-01 |
```

Foo - After

```
| pk  | foo_id | status  | created    |
|   1 |      1 | success | 2018-03-01 |
|   2 |      1 | failure | 2018-02-01 |
|   4 |      2 | success | 2018-01-01 |
|   5 |      2 | failure | 2018-01-01 |
|   6 |      3 | failure | 2018-02-01 |
```

History - After

```
| pk  | foo_id | status  | created    |
|   3 |      1 | noop    | 2018-01-01 |
|   7 |      3 | failure | 2018-01-01 |
```

is there a way to simplify/optimize this more?

Comment: Any chance of a [fiddle](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2977/34007) for this? Sample data and desired result would be a big help.

Comment: `foo_id`is not a unique identifier of a record in `foo`. Is there such a unique identifier? What's the primary key for `foo`? Can you have multiple rows with the same `foo_id` and the same `created` timestamp?

Comment: @RDFozz I've updated with some sample input/output. There will be multiple rows for foo_id (assume there is a primary key in this table but I dont believe it's relevant to the query question at hand). Also assume an entry will have at most 2 entries (one for a success status and one for a non-success status)

Comment: @Erik - When you get around to actually deleting the older entries, it may help to identify the records to keep by their primary key (or some sort of unique composite key, hence the question about whether (`foo_id`, `created`) would be unique.

Comment: @RDFozz You are totally correct! I have updated my example to account for this

Answer (score 0):

Please check the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9f363/1).

What I've done is add a surrogate unique key for each record to make it easier in the movement step. Then, in one pass I remove all records in a subquery and insert them into the archive table. This has the effect of encapsulating everything in one statement, which is handy if you're running this manually and your SQL client auto-commits after every statement (splitting things into multiple transactions).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a good old `EXISTS` approach,

```
WITH fd
     AS (DELETE FROM foo f
                WHERE f.created < now() - interval '30 days'
                      AND (f.status = 'noop'
                            OR EXISTS (SELECT *
                                              FROM foo fi
                                              WHERE fi.foo_id = f.foo_id
                                                    AND fi.status = f.status
                                                    AND fi.created > f.created))
                RETURNING foo_id,
                          status,
                          created)
INSERT INTO foo_archive (foo_id,
                         status,
                         created)
                        SELECT foo_id,
                               status,
                               created
                              FROM fd;
```

, together with two indexes,

```
CREATE INDEX foo_created
             ON foo (created);

CREATE INDEX foo_foo_id_status_created
             ON foo (foo_id,
                     status,
                     created);
```

, to support the outer as well as the inner (`EXISTS`) query.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b120a/1/0)